# Problemas al añadir objetos a un Vector

Tags: java

Estoy intentando añadir objetos a un Vector con un foreach y usando el método add(), sin embargo tengo dos problemas:

- El primero, la consola me lanza este error: *`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"`*
- El segundo: Sólo me está añadiendo al Vector el último producto que figura en la base de datos pero repetido muchas veces, en lugar de ir introduciéndome cada objeto uno por uno según va recorriendo el foreach.

Pego la parte del código a la que me refiero, el Vector listaposfacturas usuario está correctamente creado ya que lo comprobé.

```
    Vector<Producto_cantidad> listaproductocantidad=new Vector();       
    Producto_cantidad productocantidadaux=new Producto_cantidad();


    int idproducto;
    String descripcion;
    int cantidad;
    int precioUnitario;
    int precioTotal;
    int totalGeneral;



    for (POS_Factura pos_factura : listaposfacturasusuario) {


        idproducto=pos_factura.getIdproducto();
        productocantidadaux.setIdproducto(idproducto);

        descripcion=productoservice.buscar_id_producto(idproducto).getDescripcion();
        productocantidadaux.setDescripcion(descripcion);

        cantidad=pos_factura.getCantidad();
        productocantidadaux.setCantidad(cantidad);

        precioUnitario=productoservice.buscar_id_producto(idproducto).getPrecio();
        productocantidadaux.setPrecio(precioUnitario); 


        listaproductocantidad.add(productocantidadaux);
    }


    for (Producto_cantidad producto_cantidad : listaproductocantidad) {

        System.out.println(producto_cantidad.getIdproducto()+" "+producto_cantidad.getDescripcion()+" "+producto_cantidad.getCantidad()+" "+producto_cantidad.getPrecio());
    }
```

/*-------------------------------------------------------*/

El método del SERVICE de buscar_id_producto(idproducto) es:

```
public Producto findbyId(int idproducto) {
    Producto aux = null;
    try {
        plantillaSQL = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Productos where idproducto=?");
        plantillaSQL.setInt(1, idproducto); /*
                                                 * El 1 quiere decir que lo pone
                                                 * en el primer interrogante
                                                 */
        resultado = plantillaSQL.executeQuery();
        while (resultado.next()) {
            aux = new Producto();
            aux.setIdproducto(resultado.getInt("IDPRODUCTO"));
            aux.setDescripcion(resultado.getString("descripcion"));
            aux.setIdcategoria(resultado.getInt("idcategoria"));
            aux.setPrecio(resultado.getInt("precio"));
            aux.setStock(resultado.getInt("stock"));

        } // cierre while

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } // cierre catch

    return aux;
}
```

/*-------------------------------------------------------*/
El método del DAO que utilizo en el service de buscar_id_producto(idproducto) es:

```
public Producto findbyId(int idproducto) {
    Producto aux = null;
    try {
        plantillaSQL = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Productos where idproducto=?");
        plantillaSQL.setInt(1, idproducto); /*
                                                 * El 1 quiere decir que lo pone
                                                 * en el primer interrogante
                                                 */
        resultado = plantillaSQL.executeQuery();
        while (resultado.next()) {
            aux = new Producto();
            aux.setIdproducto(resultado.getInt("IDPRODUCTO"));
            aux.setDescripcion(resultado.getString("descripcion"));
            aux.setIdcategoria(resultado.getInt("idcategoria"));
            aux.setPrecio(resultado.getInt("precio"));
            aux.setStock(resultado.getInt("stock"));

        } // cierre while

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } // cierre catch

    return aux;
}
```

/*----------------------------------------*/
Bean de Producto:

package beans;

public class Producto {

```
//Atributos
private int idproducto;
private String descripcion;
private int idcategoria;
private int precio;
private int stock;

//Constructores
public Producto() {
    super();
}

public Producto(int idproducto, String descripcion, int idcategoria, int precio, int stock) {
    super();
    this.idproducto = idproducto;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
    this.idcategoria = idcategoria;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.stock = stock;
}

//Getter and Setter
public int getIdproducto() {
    return idproducto;
}

public void setIdproducto(int idproducto) {
    this.idproducto = idproducto;
}

public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}

public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public int getIdcategoria() {
    return idcategoria;
}

public void setIdcategoria(int idcategoria) {
    this.idcategoria = idcategoria;
}

public int getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}

public void setPrecio(int precio) {
    this.precio = precio;
}

public int getStock() {
    return stock;
}

public void setStock(int stock) {
    this.stock = stock;
}
```

/*------------------------------*/
Bean de Producto_cantidad que hereda de Producto

package beans;

public class Producto {

```
//Atributos
private int idproducto;
private String descripcion;
private int idcategoria;
private int precio;
private int stock;

//Constructores
public Producto() {
    super();
}

public Producto(int idproducto, String descripcion, int idcategoria, int precio, int stock) {
    super();
    this.idproducto = idproducto;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
    this.idcategoria = idcategoria;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.stock = stock;
}

//Getter and Setter
public int getIdproducto() {
    return idproducto;
}

public void setIdproducto(int idproducto) {
    this.idproducto = idproducto;
}

public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}

public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public int getIdcategoria() {
    return idcategoria;
}

public void setIdcategoria(int idcategoria) {
    this.idcategoria = idcategoria;
}

public int getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}

public void setPrecio(int precio) {
    this.precio = precio;
}

public int getStock() {
    return stock;
}

public void setStock(int stock) {
    this.stock = stock;
}
```

Comment: Suponiendo que lo que decís es correcto y listaposfacturasusuario esta correcto, el único lugar donde veo que podés tener el problema es en `buscar_id_producto(idproducto)`.  Agrega el código de ese métodos. Tal vez estés abriendo una conexión para cada elemento de la lista y esto te esté saturando la cantidad de conexiones. Lo otro hay que ver si es producto de lo mismo o por ahí un error en el query.

Comment: ¿Esa información viene toda de la base de datos? Si es así, ¿por qué no traes todo de una vez y llenas la lista luego? El error indica que sobrepasas el máximo de conexiones permitidas a la base de datos.

Comment: Ya puse el método del service y del dao que utilizo para buscar_id_producto(idproducto) así como los Bean de Producto y Producto_cantidad

Comment: Pues por lo que veo con respecto a esto `Sólo me está añadiendo al Vector el último producto que figura en la base de datos `, es porque no estás inicializando el objeto dentro del bucle, y lo haces fuera, y siempre se hace referencia al mismo sitio. Osea, pon esto dentro del bucle for `productocantidadaux=new Producto_cantidad();`, para que te crea un nuevo objeto a cada iteración.

Comment: Gracias @DiegoLoL , por lo pronto ya me agrega los objetos al Vector, el problema de las coenexiones no lo solucioné todavía. Gracias por vuestras aportaciones.

Comment: Lo que debe de estar ocurriendo es que al ejecutar el metodo findbyId() no cierras la conecciona a la base de datos. Al ejecutar el método X cantidad de veces, se te quedan en la base de datos X cantidad de conecciones abiertas llegando al limite de conecciones. Sería mas óptimo si buscas todos los productos de una vez, o utilizando un whereIn en la consulta con todos los id de los productos a buscar.
Saludos.

Answer (score -1):

MÉTODO DEL SERVICE:
    public Producto buscar_id_producto(int idproducto) {
        TransactionManager manager=null;
        manager=new TransactionManager();
        Producto aux=manager.getProductoDAO().findbyId(idproducto);
        manager.cerrarconexion();

```
    return aux;
}//cierre método buscar_id_producto
```

Comment: No uses las respuestas para añadir información, dale al botón de "editar" de la pregunta.